# Can a Promise value be sent to a function inside next() instead of a callback inside next()?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

**Question:**  Can a Promise value be sent to a function inside `next()` instead of a callback inside `next()`?

**Background:** The following standard `Promise` pattern works as expected.  *x equals 1* is sent to the console.

```js
function promisesPromises() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let x = 1;
    if (x === 1) {
      resolve('x equals 1');
    } else {
      reject('x does not equal 1');
    }
  });
}

promisesPromises()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

However when I call a function inside `.then()` instead of a callback function it throws an error.

```js
function promisesPromises() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let x = 1;
    if (x === 1) {
      resolve('x equals 1');
    } else {
      reject('x does not equal 1');
    }
  });
}

function linkOne(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

promisesPromises()
  .then(linkOne(data));
```

> ReferenceError: data is not defined

I can overcome this by placing the function inside of the callback function but this seems clunky.

```
promisesPromises()
    .then( function(data) {
        linkOne(data);
    });
```

Is there another pattern that accomplishes the same goal without placing a function inside of a callback?

Comment: you can try `promisesPromises().then(linkOne);`

Comment: `then` accepts a function, by doing `.then(linkOne(data));` you're invoking `linkOne(data)` and passing in the result which throws an error because data was not defined.

Comment: what is `next()` - where is it in the code you posted?

Comment: `Is there another pattern that accomplishes the same goal without placing a function inside of a callback?` - what is the "goal" here exactly? The argument to `then` certainly has to be a function, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` accepts a function, by doing `.then(linkOne(data));` you're invoking `linkOne(data)` and passing in the result which throws an error because data was not defined.

Another way of doing this is by using `asnyc/await`:

```
const data = await promisesPromises();
linkOne(data);
```